# Is there a way to get telemetry data for all devices belonging to a customer/asset?

Tags: thingsboard

I want to get latest telemetry for all devices belonging to specific customer or asset, such that it doesn't return only a single key/value but all the latest keys/values (for all the devices belonging to asset/customer).

Is it possible without sending multiple requests (for each device)? For example, if I want to show a table that lists all the devices belonging to an asset/customer with their latest data, can I get it by a single API call? No problem if there are several devices, but what if customer has 100 assets and each asset 100 devices? I must send 10,000 API requests to get it?

thx very much

regards, dejan

Comment: Please confirm that you only need last key/values and do not historical values?

Comment: I confirm that last values are the most important because atm I want to show a table with all the last values for a customer